# Why is the usage of util.inherits() discouraged?

Tags: node.js

According to the Node.js documentation :

> Note: usage of `util.inherits()` is discouraged. Please use the ES6 class and extends keywords to get language level inheritance support. Also note that the two styles are semantically incompatible.

https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor

Comment: I think it explains itself, what's not clear about it? If you have something built into the language, why use something more complicated, that is not optimized?

Comment: How is `util.inherits()` more complicated?

Answer (score 2):

As the quote says, you should *use the ES6 `class` and `extends` keywords to get language level inheritance support* instead of `utils.inherits` and that's exactly the reason for which to use it is discouraged: there exist better alternatives that are part of the core language, that's all.
`util.inherits` comes from the time when those utils were not part of the language and it requires you a lot of boilerplate to define your own inheritance tools.
Nowadays the language offers a valid alternative and it doesn't make sense anymore to use the ones provided with the library itself. Of course, this is true as long as you use plan to use ES6 - otherwise ignore that note and continue to use `utils.inherits`.

---

To reply to your comment:

> How is util.inherits() more complicated?

It's not a matter of being more or less complicated. To use a core language feature should be ever your preferred way over using a library specific alternative for obvious reasons.

Comment: So, how would I include `util.inherits()` using class extends?

Comment: @jimpix Uhm, no, I suspect you misunderstood it. They are exclusive, you should use one or the other, not both at the same time. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends) for further details on how `extends` works.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I meant. Using extends.

Comment: @jimpix Are you asking me how to use `extends`? This is a completely different question, you should create a new question and describe your problem in details to get help.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why `util.inherits` is discouraged, is because changing the prototype of an object should be avoided, as most JavaScript engines look for optimisations assuming that the prototype will *not* change. When it does, this may lead to bad performance.

`util.inherits` relies on [`Object.setPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) to make this change, and the MDN documentation of that native method has this warning:

> Warning: Changing the `[[Prototype]]` of an object is, by the nature of how modern JavaScript engines optimize property accesses, currently a very slow operation in every browser and JavaScript engine. In addition, the effects of altering inheritance are subtle and far-flung, and are not limited to the time spent in the `Object.setPrototypeOf(...)` statement, but may extend to any code that has access to any object whose `[[Prototype]]` has been altered.
>
> Because this feature is a part of the language, it is still the burden on engine developers to implement that feature performantly (ideally). Until engine developers address this issue, if you are concerned about performance, you should avoid setting the `[[Prototype]]` of an object. Instead, create a new object with the desired `[[Prototype]]` using `Object.create()`.

Answer (score 0):

`util.inherits()` got deprecated in the new version of node so need to use the ES6 class and extends keywords to get language level inheritance support instead of `utils.inherits`.

below example which I gave below helps you to understand more clearly :

```
"use strict";

class Person {
  constructor(fName, lName) {
    this.firstName = fName;
    this.lastName = lName;
  }

  greet() {
    console.log("in a class fn..", this.firstName, "+ ", this.lastName);
  }
}

class PoliceMan extends Person {
  constructor(burgler) {
    super("basava", "sk");
    this.burgler = burgler;
  }
}

let policeObj = new PoliceMan();

policeObj.greet();

Output : in a class fn.. basava +  sk
```

Here we can see Person class is inherited by PoliceMan class, so that PoliceMan obj can access the properties of Person class by calling `super();` in a constructor

Hope this will work as `util.inherits();`

Happy Coding !!!